# Using templates to specify member variable

Tags: c++, class, templates

Here I have a binary search tree class with a class template:

```
template <class T>
class Tree {
    T* root_ptr;
public:
    void Insert(T* ptr_to_value);
};

template <typename T>
void Tree<T>::Insert(T* ptr_to_value) {
    T** temp = &root_ptr;
    while (*temp) {
        if (ptr_to_value->name <= (*temp)->name)
            temp = &(*temp)->left_ptr;
        else
            temp = &(*temp)->right_ptr;
    }
    (*temp) = ptr_to_value;
}
```

But it refers to `name` variable of `T` class, and I may want comparison to be made with other member variable. I want something like `template </*some type*/ data>` so that I could initialize tree like `Tree<Node, name>`, or `Tree<Node, Node.name>`.

Comment: `with other member variable` what? can you please give us an example? if `Node` is always there, just use it as your `Tree<T>` member type `Node<T> root_ptr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template parameters don't have to be types; they can be certain non-types too, as long as they're compile-constants. Pointers-to-members qualify!

```
template <class T, auto Ptr>
class Tree {
    T* root_ptr;
public:
    void Insert(T* ptr_to_value);
};

template <typename T>
void Tree<T>::Insert(T* ptr_to_value)
{
    T** temp = &root_ptr;
    while (*temp) {
        if (ptr_to_value->*Ptr <= (*temp)->*Ptr)
            temp = &(*temp)->left_ptr;
        else
            temp = &(*temp)->right_ptr;
    }
    (*temp) = ptr_to_value;
}

// Tree<Foo, &Foo::name> t;
// t.insert(&val);
```

---

If you can't use `auto` template parameters, because your C++ is too old, you'll need to spell it out:

```
template <class T, class T2, T2 Tree<T>::*Ptr>
class Tree {
```

Then:

```
// Tree<Foo, std::string, &Foo::name> t;
// t.insert(&val);
```

Note, though, that Visual Studio 16.6.1 has bugs with passing pointers-to-members as template arguments, only accepting the `auto Ptr` variety at present.

Also, come to think of it, this variant might not work as I've spelt `Tree<T>` before it's known.

---

It's more conventional to pass a *comparator* as template argument, so someone can define the whole `<=` bit rather than being limited to naming a single data member. I suggest you look into how standard `map` and `set` work.

Comment: So that I initialize it like `Tree<Node, &Node.name>`?

Comment: @AlexeiSavitsky I provided sample usage.

Comment: What if substitute `Ptr` in function with `&T::Ptr`, so that I can initialize it like `Tree<Node, name>`, also it forbids to use any variables except member variables of `T`.

Comment: @AlexeiSavitsky No, you can't do that. `name` isn't a thing on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing the comparison directly in your `Insert` method, you could have your `Tree` hold a comparison function.  This is the approach that the standard containers take.

For example:

```
template <typename T, typename Comp = std::less<T>>
class Tree {
    T* root_ptr;
    Comp comp;
public:
    Tree(Comp comp = Comp{})
      : root_ptr{nullptr},
        comp{comp}
    {
    }
    void Insert(T* ptr_to_value);
};

template <typename T, typename Comp>
void Tree<T, Comp>::Insert(T* ptr_to_value) {
    T** temp = &root_ptr;
    while (*temp) {
        if (comp(*ptr_to_value, **temp))
            temp = &(*temp)->left_ptr;
        else
            temp = &(*temp)->right_ptr;
    }
    (*temp) = ptr_to_value;
}

struct Foo {
    int foo;
    Foo* left_ptr;
    Foo* right_ptr;
};

bool operator<(const Foo& left, const Foo& right) {
    return left.foo < right.foo;
}

struct CompareFoosGreater {
    bool operator()(const Foo& left, const Foo& right) {
        return left.foo > right.foo;
    }
};

int main() {
    // Defaults to using std::less, which compares
    // objects using the < operator
    Tree<Foo> foo_tree_less;
    // Use a custom comparator
    Tree<Foo, CompareFoosGreater> foo_tree_greater;
}
```

This has a couple of advantages over using a pointer to member:

1. You can compare multiple attributes
2. You can change the order elements are stored in
3. The functionality can be encoded entirely in your type